# Distance senstivitiy of onLocationChanged()

Tags: android, gps

I am a newbie with java and android. I managed to follow some tutorials to get my gps to work on an android 2.3 phone, but i notice the phone's gps is only accurate within 40 meters, which correpsonds to an accuracy of the third decimal place in latitude/longitude.

My debug log shows this change(while im sitting on my laptop, typing)

```
LOCATION CHANGED(2137): 43.522701025009155
LOCATION CHANGED(2137): -72.13161981105804
LOCATION CHANGED(2137): 43.522695660591125
LOCATION CHANGED(2137): -72.13161981105804
```

This is my code

```
  public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if (location != null) {
        Log.d("LOCATION CHANGED", location.getLatitude() + "");
        Log.d("LOCATION CHANGED", location.getLongitude() + "");
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
            location.getLatitude() + "" + location.getLongitude(),
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else{
           // Log.v(TAG,"LOCATION not found");

        }
       // Log.d("LOCATION is", location.getLatitude() + "");

    }
```

Is it possible to change the onLocationChanged() function to something like 
public void onLocationChanged(Location location, minimumdistance_changed)

where minimumdistance_changed is the accuracy of the current accuracy of gps. I'll also be happy with just setting the minimumdistance_changed value to 100meters as long as it will mean i only get a reading from onLocationChanged when the gps value changes to the third decimal place.

Answer (score 1):

Upon requesting location updates from the location manager you can specify a minimum distance between updates:

```
lm.requestLocationUpdates(provider, timeBetweenUpdates, distBetweenUpdates, listener);
```

But is is only a hint, the system is not required to follow your hint.